# MSWord how to unlink/break first link to excel document, without breaking remaining set of hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office

I want to set up a word template, which has a linked excel table via a field with following code:

**{LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 D:\calendar.xlsm calendar!namedR \f 4 \h \* MERGEFORMAT}**

The table resides in excel and is updated daily. The excel has several columns and one of them has a set of hyperlinks to various websites in rows. When I try to break the link to the table, in order to create rest of the document and archive it via the following code, I always get all of the links (including hyperlinks to websites) in the linked table broken. 
The funny thing is that when I do it manually and select the table in Word it breaks only the link to the excel table, leaving the hyperlinks in a table column intact. This is the desired programmatic outcome. I tried 2 following macros and none of them works. Is there a way to achieve it via VBA without breaking all the links in a linked table?

```
Sub ConvertTableLink()

    Dim myField As Field

   For Each myField In ActiveDocument.Fields
      If myField.Type = wdFieldLink Then
         myField.Unlink
      End If
   Next

End Sub

Sub ConvertTableLinkTake2()

   ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Update
   ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Unlink

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, there is no error whatsoever. The problem is that in the word file the linked table to excel includes a column with inserted hyperlinks to different websites (they reside originally in excel and point to various websites (https://....). These links are inserted manually by users in the excel table. However, the macro breaks all these links in the table in word, hence after running the macro they are basically useless. I would like to break only the link to the excel table, without destroying the content of the column and remaining links, as they will be needed in the final document.

Comment: You cannot unlink a field without unlinking all the fields within it. The approach given by slightly snarky will only work if the URL and display text are the same; otherwise, you'll need to capture all the hyperlink URLs & display texts before unlink, so you can use Find/Replace on the range post-unlinking to restore the hyperlinks corresponding to the now-unlinked display texts.

Comment: Ok, I understand, this seems to be the good workaround. Still, I wonder how it is possible that when breaking the link via the Excel controls (right click on the linked table | Links | Break link or via the Edit links dialog as in the [article] (https://wordribbon.tips.net/T006010_Breaking_a_Document_Link.html) works correnctly leaving the remaining column hyperlinks intact. It seems that internally Excel is capable of achieving this.

Comment: What is more, when I check the properties of the field (both via doc.Fields.Count or doc.Fields(1) and following number I get the correct fields (doc.Fields(1) is for the table, and the following numbers are for the hyperlinks), however when I try to unlink this particular link, it unlinks whole set of links in the table, as you have stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not obvious why your links are remaining when you unlink the LINK field manually but not with VBA. Generally speaking, I see the same behavior whichever way I do it here - the links remain blue so they still look like links, but they aren't.

You can do your own "unlink" that should preserve the hyperlinks using this, assuming the LINK is the first LINK field in the document:

```
Sub replaceLinkByResult1()
Dim fld As Word.Field
Dim rng As Word.Range
For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
  If fld.Type = wdFieldLink Then
    Set rng = fld.Result.Tables(1).Range
    rng.Copy
    fld.Delete
    rng.Paste
    Exit For
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

If Copy/Paste doesn't work or you prefer to avoid it, the following should also work:

```
Sub replaceLinkByResult2()
Dim fld As Word.Field
Dim rng1 As Word.Range
Dim rng2 As Word.Range
For Each fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
  If fld.Type = wdFieldLink Then
    Set rng1 = fld.Result.Tables(1).Range
    Set rng2 = rng1.Duplicate
    rng2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rng2.Start = rng2.Start + 1
    rng2.InsertParagraph
    rng2.Start = rng2.Start + 1
    rng2.FormattedText = rng1.FormattedText
    fld.Delete
    Set rng2 = Nothing
    Set rng1 = Nothing
    Exit For
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, assuming the linked object is the first field in the document:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range, Hlnk As Hyperlink, i As Long
Dim StrDisp As String, StrLink As String, StrFont As String, StrSize As String
With ActiveDocument.Fields(1)
  Set Rng = .Result
  With Rng
    For Each Hlnk In .Hyperlinks
      StrDisp = StrDisp & "|" & Hlnk.TextToDisplay
      StrLink = StrLink & "|" & Hlnk.Address
      StrFont = StrFont & "|" & Hlnk.Range.Font.Name
      StrSize = StrSize & "|" & Hlnk.Range.Font.Size
    Next
  End With
  .Unlink
  With Rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(Split(StrDisp, "|"))
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .Text = Split(StrDisp, "|")(i)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
      End With
      Set Hlnk = .Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=.Duplicate, Address:=Split(StrLink, "|")(i), TextToDisplay:=Split(StrDisp, "|")(i))
      Hlnk.Range.Font.Name = Split(StrFont, "|")(i)
      Hlnk.Range.Font.Size = Split(StrSize, "|")(i)
    Next
  End With
End With
End Sub
```